# How to Store A Json Array or Json Object in mysql using Spring And Mybatis

Tags: spring-mvc, mybatis

### Controller.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = { ControllerUriConstant.add }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ActivityMapping(activity = ActivityEnum.ADD)
public String addActivities(@ModelAttribute("activityForm") ActivityForm activityForm, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model,
        HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    new ActivityFormValidator().validate(activityForm, bindingResult, request.getLocale(), getMessageSource(), null, activityService);
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAttribute(Constants.ACTIVITY_FORM,activityForm );
        model.addAttribute(Constants.HAS_ERROR, Boolean.TRUE);
        model.addAttribute("add", true);
        model.addAttribute(Constants.ERROR_MESSAGE, getMessageSource().getMessage("ulearn.messages.add.failed", activityForm.getName()));
        return "activityform";
    } else {
        model.addAttribute(Constants.SUCCESS_MESSAGE, getMessageSource().getMessage("ulearn.messages.add.success", activityForm.getName()));
        JSONArray address =new JSONArray();
        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
        jo.put("id", "1");
        jo.put("name","Test");
        JSONObject jo1= new JSONObject();
        jo1.put("id", "1");
        jo1.put("name", "Test2");
        JSONObject jo2= new JSONObject();
        jo2.put("id", "1");
        jo2.put("name", "Test3");
        address.add(jo);
        address.add(jo1);
        address.add(jo2);

        activityForm.setInsertJsonMysql(address);
        activityService.add(activityForm);
    }
    return getActivities( model, request);
}
```

### Service.java

```
public void add(ActivityForm activityForm) throws TechnoShineException {
    try {
        Activity activity = new Activity();
        activity.setName(activityForm.getName());
        activity.setActive(activityForm.getActive());
        activity.setInsertJsonMysql(activityForm.getInsertJsonMysql());
        activityDAO.getMapper().insert(activity);
        logAudit(getAuditableList(activity, null), getMessageSource().getMessage("ulearn.messages.add.success", activity.getName()), 0, ActivityEnum.ADD);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new TechnoShineException(e, ActivityService.class);
    }
}
```

### Mapper.xml

```
<insert id="insert" parameterType="com.technoshinelabs.ulearn.persistance.bean.controlpanel.Activity">
    INSERT INTO activity (activity_name,is_active,json_array)
    VALUES (#{name},#{active},#{insertJsonMysql})
</insert>
```

// Finally got this error error Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Type handler was null on parameter mapping for property 'insertJsonMysql'.  It was either not specified and/or could not be found for the javaType / jdbcType combination specified.

> > [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeZeR.png

Comment: I think mybatis typeHandler will help you

Answer (score 0):

I suppose what you want to store is the actual JSON and the MySQL table column *json_array* is of type *VARCHAR* or *TEXT*.

JSONArray is actually but an utility class used to build the JSON.

Then you shall change the type of property *insertJsonMysql* of class *Activity* to *String* and set it to the String representation of the *JSONArray*.

```
activity.setInsertJsonMysql(activityForm.getInsertJsonMysql().toString());
```

EDIT: about inserting into enum column.

According to [MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html), I would say you insert into enum typed column the same way you insert any String, the DB will check provided value against list of values declared in *CREATE TABLE*.

But according to the code sample you provide, the value for *insertJsonMysql* will be:

```
[{"id":"1","name":"Test1"},{"id":"1","name":"Test2"},{"id":"1","name":"Test3"}]
```

that means one of the enum values would have to be this exact string.

However, I feel like that's not what you expect. Maybe using a [SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set.html) typed column is a closer answer.

Comment: please, edit your question to provide material that will help figuring out what you try to achieve

Comment: How do i store the same json Array as a Enum type instead of varchar/text in mysql

Comment: You should add this complementary question at the end of your orignal post so that other readers understand the overall question/answers. I will amend my answer for Enum.